# SSL connection reset with restbed

Tags: openssl, restbed

I have a 64bit windows application that hosts a REST server using restbed, it was built with Visual Studio 2015.

When I test the REST API using the python scripts with the debug build all works fine without any errors, however when I test the same program using the release build I randomly get socket connection exceptions thrown in the python code. e.g.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 313, in recv_into
    return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1840, in recv_into
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1663, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise SysCallError(errno, errorcode.get(errno))
OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')
```

I am using requests V2.23.0 & pyOpenSSL V19.1.0.
My certificate is self-signed.

Any suggestions? Is there a way of forcing restbed to use tlsv1.2 so that I can use wireshark to see what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended being nothing to do with HTTPS or even HTTP. But due to having data left on the socket when the session was closed. This resulted in the socket being closed with the Reset flag set instead of the FIN flag. Was a bug in the processing of the requests on the server side! Opps.

Comment: Could you add more details about the problem and how you fixed it?
We seem to have the same issue with restbed where client requests are dropping with CONNECTION_RESET and it's also intermittent.

Comment: It was fixed by making sure that all of the data from the socket that was sent by the python test scripts was read.

Comment: That is exactly what was going on! My client was sending unexpected data in the request that if left unread on the server would intermittently drop the connection during the response data transmission. Thanks!